# Could anti-cheat systems trigger false positives if I open my favorite games through Python using subprocess.Popen?

Tags: windows, python, operating-systems, process

This may be hard to answer definitively.

I feel like the answer is **no**, but I'm looking for people familiar with anti-cheat and/or operating systems in general to confirm or deny this.

I know apps opened like this don't *appear* to run in a container inside the Python process or anything like that (in Task Manager), but after all they are initially triggered by a script. Does anyone know if they behave or look different to the operating system or to these anti-cheat systems?

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends". Given the information you've given and the nature of the question, no answer more specific than that will be honest or accurate.

Comment: I guess I could have worded the question better as "can a Windows program in any way detect that it was opened through Python's `subprocess.Popen` (which calls `CreateProcess`)?"

Comment: Yes a process can determine what methods were used to open it, and can take actions based on that information.